# Inheritance in react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-component

Please consider a following case:

I have created a "baseUser" component which is a form having three fields username, password and name. Now I want this form in three different applications : Application1, Application2 and Application3.

1. In Application1, User component should use this baseUser component but want only two fields (username, password) from baseUser state and should also have two additional fields which is first-name and last-name.
2. In Application2 and Application3, User component should work same as the baseUser.
3. Also all the actions, events, states should be able to work alone and be able to overridden.

The render method should also be overridden as their can be different UIs for different applications.

How can we achieve this functionality using react components? Does inheriting "baseUser" in applications using "extends" cause any issue (Or is it correct way to do it)?

Comment: You can make one common component taking parameters and render it in app1, app2 and app3 by providing each's specific need. For ex, for app1 just pass uname, pwd and name and on the bases of params the common component will return that much of fields. and same applies to each app2 and app3 components.

Answer (score 0):

React does not use `Inheritance`. You can't extend a react component. React basically work on the `Composition`. Composition means, creating small parts and combine them together to make a complete part.

Now, in your situation. There are only 3 input fields into your `baseUsr` component and you want to use only two of them into your `application1`. Simply you can't do this. You have to render complete `baseUsr` component.

You are getting the concept of components wrong. Think about components like a function or part of UI that is abstract or can be used in standalone. 
For example, you can create a `Header` component because it can be used in isolation and can be used on multiple pages. But an `input` field in a `form` can not be used in isolation.

This confusion is created because you create components just like classes in javascript but they are the basic building block of UI.
For more information read [Composition VS inheritance on React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)

Comment: You can extend a react component, that's how it was done until they recommend using functional components.  React discourages using class inheritance nowadays , but you can if you wish to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your baseUser this way:

```
class BaseUserForm extends Component {

     handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        const data = { ...this.state.data };
        data[input.name] = input.value;
        this.setState({ data });  //state is in inheriated form.
      };

      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        //Form validation
        if (!errors) this.doSubmit();
      };

      renderInput = (name, label, type = "text") => {
        return (
          <Input
            name={name}
            label={label}
            type={type}
            error={this.state.errors[name]}
            value={this.state.data[name]}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        );
      };

      renderButton = (label, type = "submit") => {
        return (
          <button
            type={type}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            // disabled={this.validate()}
          >
            {label}
          </button>
        );
      };
    }

export default BaseUserForm;
```

Then depending on your Application, you can add/remove input fields as needed.

```
class AppForm extends BaseUserForm{
    state={
       data:{username:"",
             password:""}
       };

 doSubmit = () => {
      //Do your submit here.
  };

    render(){
       return(
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
           {this.renderInput("username", "User Name")}
           {this.renderInput("password", "Password")}
           //Add more field as needed.
         </form>
       );
    }
}
```